# How to execute long run program in php

Tags: php

A ruby program which generates multiple output and prints multiple lines, it normally runs around 1-2 min in terminal.

I am trying to run the same program in php. I have tried using `system()`, `passthru()` and `exec()`. However, it starts to run and just prints the first 2 lines and immediately the program terminates. Is there a way to run 1-2 min running program in php?

Comment: Is there an error when terminating? Do you run the PHP code from console or webserver?

Comment: No there is no errors.

Comment: Are you running this from the terminal or through the browser

Comment: Running through browser. If I run in terminal it works fine.

Comment: Maybe a problem with permissions. Does the webserver owner have enough permissions?

Comment: Yes it has enough permission. I tried running small programs, it works. But with long time consuming program, it terminates.

Comment: 1. This question has nothing to do with [tag:ruby], you might test with `sleep(100)` as well; 2. Spawn the process with [`nohup`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm) and get the returned value [if needed] afterwards.

Comment: seems like your webserver terminates request handling. What do you see in web-app logs? in a browser? what web-server do you use?

Answer (score 0):

3 things to look into:

1. PHP runtime configuration: [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)
2. Apache's [Timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) directive
3. Permission of the Ruby script. Is it executable by the user running Apache?

Comment: This suggests to allow the browser to hang up for minutes waiting for the external command to be executed. This approach is plain wrong.

Comment: The OP intended to run a *long running* process with PHP. If OP wants to "fire and forget", he could raise another question. Although it's just as simple as appending ` &> /dev/null &` to the cmd.